# SQL Grouping and counting using existing row

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say we have a table `Requests` with structure:

```
user_id 
product_id 
count
```

With entries like:

```
1 1 5  
1 2 6  
1 1 3
2 1 7
2 1 3
2 2 5
```

I want to count how much of each product each user has.

And get output like this:

```
1 1 8
1 2 6
2 1 10
2 2 5
```

Comment: Edit: removed **Wow, that was easy! Thank you!!**. There is no need to "thank", just "accept answer" and "up vote" it's the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GROUP BY with the [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregate function:

```
SELECT user_id, product_id, SUM(count) AS total
FROM Requests
GROUP BY user_id, product_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT user_id, product_id, SUM(`count`)
FROM Requests
GROUP BY user_id, product_id
```

I wouldn't name a field "count" if I had the choice, as it's a SQL function and could cause weird naming conflicts down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a tutorial on how to use `GROUP BY` here:

- [SQL GROUP BY statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

You can also find specific information on the syntax and use of GROUP BY in MySQL in the MySQL Manual:

- [MySQL SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)
- [MySQL GROUP BY Functions And Modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html)